# How many three-digit numbers can be formed if only odd numbers are allowed to be re - used?

Tags: combinatorics

Professor told us to interpret the problem as "Do not use more than one even number when making the three-digit numbers". My work...

Case 1: ODD_ODD_ODD, hence, 5*5*5 = 125.

Case 2: ODD_ODD_EVEN, hence, 5*5*5 = 125.

Case 3: ODD_EVEN_ODD, hence, 5*5*5 = 125.

Case 4: EVEN_ODD_ODD, hence, 4*5*5 = 100.

125 + 225 + 125 + 100 = 475.

Am I double counting?

Comment: You are not double counting, there are no intersections in your cases. Now, I don't know if it's me but this interpretation "Do not use more than one even number when making the three-digit numbers" doesn't seem natural. At the beginning I interpreted it as "Do not use an even number more than once when making the three-digit numbers" (so for example 243 or 246 would be an allowed number with my interpretation)

Answer (score 0):

Your title and first sentence are incompatible.

The title would imply $478$ is valid but your first sentence would not.  The number $4$ is not re-used.

Please fix your problem statement... in particular, the title.